# How to make chrome extension's icon be changed automatically when extension's icon file changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use an unpacked chrome extension. While Chrome is running, if I change icon file with another file which has same name in extension folder, browser does not show the new icon.

But if I restart the browser, extension's icon will be changed.

Can I do these icon replacement without restarting browser?

PS: It is possible with Chrome DevTools, I know it. Can I do this without DevTools?

Comment: Right click your extension icon, choose Manage (it will open chrome://extensions), click Reload.

Comment: You have to reload the extension again. By clicking on Reload link on extension page.